# Unable to connect to snap store from Ubuntu Software Center & Ubuntu Single Sign On

Tags: 18.04, software-center, single-sign-on

When I'm trying to install some of the applications through the Ubuntu Software center, it is asking me to authenticate with snap store. After i key in the username and password, when i press the continue button, it just reloads the same screen.

I have tried adding the account through the Ubuntu single sign on under the online account and getting the error "Error connecting to Ubuntu Single Sign-On server: Provided email/password is not correct" (second screenshot)

Ubuntu 18.04

[image: Software Center Authentication Screen]

[image: Ubuntu Single Sign On Error]